# Como categorizar valores em um Data Frame no R?

Tags: r

Em um Data Frame tenho uma coluna com o índice de vulnerabilidade social (`IVS`), que varia de `0` a `1` por município. Eu preciso agrupar alguns valores para que fique como o exemplo:

```
#Como Está                            #Como preciso que fique
Município   IVS                       Município    IVS 
A           0.488                     A            Alta
B           0.253                     B            Baixa
C           0.158                     C            Muito Baixa
D           0.685                     D            Muito alta
```

Como proceder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se quiser se ater ao pacote base, pode usar indexação e múltiplas comparações:

```
set.seed(123)
dados <- data.frame(
  Municipio = LETTERS[1:6],
  IVS = runif(6)
)

dados$IVScat[dados$IVS < .33] <- 'baixo'
dados$IVScat[dados$IVS >= .33 & dados$IVS < .66] <- 'medio'
dados$IVScat[dados$IVS >= .66] <- 'alto'

> dados
  Municipio       IVS IVScat
1         A 0.2875775  baixo
2         B 0.7883051   alto
3         C 0.4089769  medio
4         D 0.8830174   alto
5         E 0.9404673   alto
6         F 0.0455565  baixo
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Deu certinho

Comment: Não é necessário agradecer, o voto já conta. Mas se tiver muitas categorias e/ou precisar repetir a classificação diversas vezes, creio que [a solução proposta pelo Rui Barradas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344847/117168) é melhor.

Answer (score 6):

Como você não forneceu as faixas de categorização, estipulei-as subjetivamente para responder. A função `recode`, do package `car`, resolve o problema:

```
library(car)

dataset<-data.frame(Município=c(LETTERS[1:4]),IVS=c(0.488,0.253,0.158,0.685))

dataset$novavariavel<-recode(dataset$IVS,
'0:0.2="Muito Baixa";
0.21:0.35="Baixa";
0.36:0.5="Alta";
0.51:1="Muito Alta"')

#> dataset
#  Município   IVS novavariavel
#1         A 0.488         Alta
#2         B 0.253        Baixa
#3         C 0.158  Muito Baixa
#4         D 0.685   Muito Alta
```

- `dataset$novavariavel` é a nova coluna que você deseja criar, com as categorias desejadas.
- as faixas de categorização você pode definir a seu critério. Sempre que a categorização for uma 'palavra', é preciso utilizar `"` como fiz no exemplo.

Answer (score 5):

Ainda outra maneira é com a função `findInterval`, que creio ser neste caso melhor que a função `cut`.

Se tivermos vetores de novos `niveis` e de pontos `limite` o seguinte resolve o problema.

```
niveis <- c("Muito Baixa", "Baixa", "Alta", "Muito Alta")
limites <- c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1)

i <- findInterval(ivs$IVS, limites)
i
#[1] 3 2 1 4

niveis[i]
#[1] "Alta"        "Baixa"       "Muito Baixa" "Muito Alta"
```

Então é só correr uma linha de código. Aqui está em duas para manter o original.

```
novo <- data.frame(Município = ivs$Município)
novo$IVS <- niveis[findInterval(ivs$IVS, limites)]

novo
#  Município         IVS
#1         A        Alta
#2         B       Baixa
#3         C Muito Baixa
#4         D  Muito Alta
```